# Preventing Windows Update from installing drivers programmatically

Tags: windows, driver, updates

I've just red some threads about this, but I didn't find a successful solution.
    So, I have installed a windows driver for a device, BUT I DON'T WANT IT TO BE UPDATED by Windows (7,8,8.1,10) Update.
    I would like to disable Win Update Search programmatically.
    I have used, from command line:

```
REGEDIT /S <myfile.txt>
```

Where `<myfile.txt>` contains:

```
     `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DriverSearching]
"SearchOrderConfig"=dword:00000002`
```

But it doesn't give me any result.
After trying the command, I verify the configuration going to:
`Computer->Advanced System Settings->Hardware...`
but the options in the dialog are the same there was before `REGEDIT`command.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your text file as follows:

- Make the first line of the file `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00`
- Remove the backticks (``) from the start and end of the command.
- Remove the leading space or tab before `[HKEY...`
- Save the file in `unicode`, not `ascii`.
- Change the file extension from `.txt` to `.reg`.

Finally, note that the value you want for `SearchOrderConfig` to be "Never update" is `3` not `2`

I've tested that this works and changes the visible values in the `Advanced System Settings`.